# OpenGL 2.1+ Render with data returned form assimp library

Tags: opengl, c, assimp

I have just read [this tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/#comment-14551) about how to load a 3D model file. Its render routine uses a `recursive_render` function to scan all nodes.

**My question:**

1. What does a `aiNode` struct store?
2. What the difference between this method and above method:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < scene->mNumMesh; ++i) {
      draw scene->mMeshes[i];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The aiNode struct is defined in the Assimp library. [**Here**](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_node.html) you can find it its definition on the official documentation:

```
Public Attributes
aiNode **       mChildren       // The child nodes of this node.
unsigned int *  mMeshes         // The meshes of this node.
aiString        mName           // The name of the node.
unsigned int    mNumChildren    // The number of child nodes of this node.
unsigned int    mNumMeshes      // The number of meshes of this node.
aiNode *        mParent         // Parent node.
aiMatrix4x4     mTransformation // The transformation relative to the node's parent.
```

2) I don't know what is the difference between "your method" and `recursive_render`, but looks like you are missing a lot of information (childs, etc). I'd have a closer look to `recursive_render`

Comment: thanks for reply, that is what i do not understands, why they are divided model into more "nodes" but not only meshes?

Comment: For a definition of "node", I recommend that you read the section about "The Node Hierarchy" from http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html. "A node can potentially refer to single or multiple meshes. The meshes are not stored inside the node, but instead in an array of aiMesh inside the aiScene. A node only refers to them by their array index. This also means that multiple nodes can refer to the same mesh, which provides a simple form of instancing."